# How to redirect after login to a UserProfile view

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using `react-redux` for some login logic in my `reactjs` app. The normal login works just fine. But I am trying to redirect to `/profile` when the user has not filled out some information for his UserProfile. If the user has already a profile, then redirect to `/` after login.

I have an api to check if user has a profile already. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hasProfile/`

Login.js

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.props.onAuth(values.userName, values.password);
        this.props.history.push('/profile/');
      }
    });
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAuth: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password))
    }
}
```

auth.js

```
export const authLogin = (username, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authStart());
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .then(res => {
            const token = res.data.key;
            const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate);
            dispatch(authSuccess(token));
            dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(3600));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(authFail(err))
        })
    }
}
```

What would be a good way to accomplish this? add another `.then` in authLogin to call the hasProfile api? But where would be the best place to redirect to '/' or '/profile' based on the response from hasProfile?

reducers.js

```
const initialState = {
    token: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false
}

const authSuccess = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        token: action.token,
        error: null,
        loading: false
    });
}
...
```

auth.js

```
export const authSuccess = token => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS,
        token: token
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your user has profile or not inside your login method of backend, then return both variables like

```
{
  token: "your token",
  hasProfile: true
}
```

Then you can render desired component based on that

```
render() {
  const { user } = this.props;

  if (user&& user.hasProfile) {
    return <Home />;
  }

  if (user&& !user.hasProfile) {
    return <Profile />;
  }

  return <Login />;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am solving this problem by using         this.props.history.push('/') inside handleSubmit and then calling checkIfProfileExists from componentWillReceiveProps inside '/'

```
checkIfProfileExists = (token) => {
     axios.defaults.headers = {
     "Accept": "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     'Authorization': "Token " + token
     }


     axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hasProfile').then(res => {

     let hasProfile = res.data[0].hasProfile
     if(hasProfile) {
         this.props.history.push('/');
     }
     else {
         this.props.history.push('/profile/');
     }
 })
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {

    this.checkIfProfileExists(newProps.token)

}
```